# Suppress logo in header based on a formula field determined later

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to suppress a logo based on a boolean `@Accredited` that changes later in the report.

```
if {@Accredited} = false then
    true
else
    false
```

The image is in the header, but `@Accredited` is further down and updated from a subreport. That all works great, but the header suppression doesn't seem to work. It's as if it checks if `@Accredited` is true or false the first time but never refreshes.  How can I make sure the logo suppression checks after the report is finished completely?

This is the `@Accredited` formula:

```
Shared booleanvar bAccredited;

bAccredited;
```

`bAccredited` is set inside the subreport.  This way I can see the value returned when debugging. There is more going on inside of the subreport, but it ultimately sets `bAccredited` to true or false, which is then picked up and displayed properly by `@Accredited`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `whileprintingrecords;` which forces a formula to evaluate after the records have been loaded, but before things are displayed on the page.

Rewrite your suppression formula to look like this:

```
Whileprintingrecords;
{@Accredited} = false
```

---

If this fails to work, you may have the option of making another subreport in the header, which performs the same calculations necessary to determine whether or not the header displays. From there you can grab the boolean return value and suppress.

Comment: This is working, but the logo is used on multiple pages.  Is there a way to handle this across pages as well?

Comment: @sdouble In that case, perhaps look into the second option I suggested. That way every time your header is evaluated, it checks to see whether or not to display.